# Where to save 5MB of data?

Tags: json, database

I've a personal aplication that stores on LocalStorage a little amount of data (max 5 MB).
I want make an app for my smartphone using that data and at the same time keep synchronized with my computer.
So for do this what is the best way? Pay a server? There is a free way?
Sorry for any spell mistake.

Comment: Do you need the data synchronized always? If not you could keep the data on your smartphone, and only sync when you have wifi connection at home.

Comment: Not always. That could be a good way. For do this I'll need to make a server on my computer right?

Comment: You can also copy the database from your mobile to your PC. Google for "transfer files from android to pc wifi" or "share files from mobile to pc" (or something like that), then no server will be needed.

Comment: Good! Thanks a lot.